# Why VLookUP not work with large text

Tags: excel-formula

I use a formula for copying data from sheet2 to sheet1 with this formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,COLUMN(),FALSE),"")
```

It works well. But It doesn't work with large text. 
My text example:

```
http://www.imdb.com/offsite/?page-action=offsite-warnerbros&token=BCYjjcO9abopG7_2269JEn7520-r1f47KXvVIHfXH9dnHF2X3Dl07RaPqaEf8uh7ByYPH-tpY4mE%0D%0AFfjrAfF563s_sY8adxepid38SNgmJgrgRHMj5Oc0ffeB2tQe6wuVo68X5BQTu6B5uGGeMdQWKvZM%0D%0AelqFAg7XgXLNFluju2rwoseKKst4rCNtHlnnjk7a4PSCCKR6CPNEEvA45VGl1fdOJ5qThsifWItR%0D%0AefPnChuWEX4%0D%0A&ref_=tt_pdt_ofs_offsite_1
```

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/247427/255-character-limit-on-vlookup

Answer (score 0):

Applying [@barry's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204015/1505120) to what I am guessing is where and what you want, maybe:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Sheet2!A:A=A1,0),0)),"")
```