# Excel Match on Multiple Criteria with Characters Length > 256

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, string-length

I am trying to build of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202473/way-to-overcome-excel-vlookup-function-limit-of-256-characters) and incorporate it for multiple matches.

I have a formulas like this:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(G:G=A2&E:E=B2,0),0)
=MATCH(TRUE,AND(INDEX(G:G=A2,0),INDEX(E:E=B2,0)),0)
```

but it's not working.

How can I extend this to incorporate two or more match criteria that will capture values I have > 256 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` function doesn't work in these sort of formulas because it returns a single result, not an array You can use * to multiply the conditions like this

`=MATCH(1,INDEX((G:G=A2)*(E:E=B2),0),0)`

Note: Lookup value needs to be 1 because multiplying Booleans gives you 1/0 values

`INDEX` function isn't strictly necessary - just used here to avoid "array entry". You can also use this version

`=MATCH(1,(G:G=A2)*(E:E=B2),0)`

but that requires <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>